# Browser showing blank page after implementing html code from template into react jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am working on a react project using typescript, and I when I run the app on the browser, it shows a blank page. But when I remove this: (className="animsition") from the first div, the page loads. This is the code in App.tsx:

```
function App() {
return (
<div className="App">
  <div className="animsition">
    <header>
      <h1>React App</h1>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
);
}
```

And here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
        <title>React App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="animsition/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the main.js file:

```
 (function ($) {
     "use strict";

     $(".animsition").animsition({
     inClass: "fade-in",
     outClass: "fade-out",
     inDuration: 1500,
     outDuration: 800,
     linkElement: ".animsition-link",
     loading: true,
     loadingParentElement: "html",
     loadingClass: "animsition-loading-1",
     loadingInner: '<div class="loader05"></div>',
     timeout: false,
     timeoutCountdown: 5000,
     onLoadEvent: true,
     browser: ["animation-duration", "-webkit-animation-duration"],
     overlay: false,
     overlayClass: "animsition-overlay-slide",
     overlayParentElement: "html",
     transition: function (url) {
     window.location.href = url;
     },
   });
 })(jQuery);
```

And here is a screenshot for Sources in chrome:
[image]

I pasted the code in CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/v97zv8

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To help better understand, could you please add a bit of indentation to your html and provide the full document (here we can't see the closing tags, hence we don't know if there is something else imported)
Also since you import a javascript script (main.js) please provide the script with your question.
To narrow down the possible issues. Provide a screenshot of your "Sources" devtools tab for localhost, to check if all your ressources are loaded as expected

Comment: Ok I will edit the question.

Comment: any CSS you applied? If yes can you share it

Comment: better to recreate the problem in a Fiddle or code sandbox

Comment: @AnujPanwar yes but the css file is too long. I don't think I can paste it here.

Comment: Since all files are imported as expected, you should recreate your issue in a codeSandbox are share it here

Comment: Here is the link from codeSandbox: https://v97zv8.csb.app/

Comment: Well, `.animsition` class has `opacity: 0` so everything inside is transparent

Comment: @AlexChashin yes but the script works in a way that the animation fades in, so yes it is 0 at start but when it fades in and turns to 1

Comment: but in it has the clearly opacity:0 either you can use animation here property here which will have opacity:1 at 100% or you can use the another class if animation done